# Trimming or spackling the edge of a tile schluter to drywall (Large Gap)

Tags: drywall, tile, painting, trim, carpentry

I would like to get any suggestions for closing this gap. The bathroom studs were out of plumb in an older house.

The edge of the schluter goes from 0 at the bottom to 3/4" at the top on one side. And the other side it goes from 0 to 1/4".

I attempted quick dry spackle to fill the gap and it looks horrendous. Does anyone have any ideas of certain trim (corner round won't lay flat) or possibly doing a second coat of good smooth spackle?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes aesthetics are more important than "level, square, and plumb".

Try scraping that stuff back a bit and doing it over with [lightweight topping compound](http://www.paletteapp.com/assets/Products/usg/beadex-lite-topping-126601_large.jpg). Use a smooth clean knife and the stuff goes on like butter, and it's easy to sand smooth after it sets. Hit it with primer and paint and it will look as good as it is going to.

Comment: If the wall would have been left out of plumb, the tile could have been weird looking in the corner.

Comment: Nope, keep the corner perfect. Always keep perfect the places where the eye is drawn to. You accommodate out of plumb walls by slightly trimming the tiles out at the edge, to keep a plumb vertical line there too.

Answer (score 0):

[DuraBond](https://www.usg.com/content/usgcom/en/products-solutions/products/finishing/setting-type-powder-joint-compounds/usg-sheetrock-durabond-joint-compound.html) works great in bathrooms, and anywhere else, that you have a large gap to fill.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a setting type compound (durabond or USG easy bond type) for this because it will enable a deeper fill with less shrinkage and also, in my experience, does a bit better with humidity over time in bathrooms and other wet settings.

Are you concerned about the actual little gap/indentation in the joint compound or the fact that the reveal on the schluter trim and the filler that's under it is inconsistent?

You can float the surface of the wall up with joint compound to make the reveal of the schluter trim and space below it more consistent with the trim. This is typically done in lots of instances. For example, if window casing is proud to the wall and the window jamb cannot be planed, contractors often float the surface of the wall up to the trim so that a gap is not evident.

Do yourself a favor and tape the edge of the schluter trim very well with good blue tape before you do any more compounding or painting near it. It is a PITA to clean.